# Removing a node in an XML before flattening via the flatxml package in R

Tags: r, xml, xml-parsing, xml2

I have multiple XMLs that I'd like to extract data from that were created from PDFs using a machine learning library.

When using the flatxml package in R, I am running into an issue importing the XML via `fxml_importXMLFlat()` where whenever there is a `<ref>` tag within a `<p>` node, it cuts off all the data after `</ref>` that is in the `<p>` node.  So in the example XML below, everything starting at

> . Predominately amorphous (non-crystalline ..."

until `</p>` would get cut off.

```
<text xml:lang="en">
<body>
<div xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
<head n="1.">Introduction</head>
<p>
Thermal properties of confectionary products, including the melting temperature (Tm) of crystalline components and glass transition temperature (Tg) of amorphous components, as well as the crystalline to amorphous ratio, significantly impact system texture and stability
<ref type="bibr" target="#b23">(Levine and Slade, 1986)</ref>
. Predominantly amorphous (non-crystalline, disordered solid) candies are formed by heating ingredients to a set temperature and then quickly cooling the resultant supersatured sugar solution to below the temperature range in which recrystallization of sugars can occur, between Tg and Tm of the material. 
</p>
</body>
</text>
```

To get around this issue, I planned to import the files into R as XMLs initially, removing the `<ref>` tags, then flattening via flatxml.

I have tried using the XML package to find and remove the `<ref>` tags using the following code:

```
xml1 <- read_xml("https://file.io/vAiDRi5s68Gm")

ref <- xml_find_all(xml1, "//ref")

rm(ref)
```

and it returns nothing in the ref object. When I look at the xml after it is read in, it doesn't look like any of the tags are `<ref>` either.

I also tried
 `xml1 <- xmltoList("https://file.io/vAiDRi5s68Gm")` but it doesn't seem to find the `<ref>` tag either.

I also tried
 `xml1 <- xmlToDateFrame("https://file.io/vAiDRi5s68Gm")` and I get the following error:

> Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, names(nodes[[i]]), value = c(text = "\n\t\t", :
> duplicate subscripts for columns

which as I understand is because the XML file is super nested.

My aim is to extract data from hundreds of XMLs so I need something that I can apply to all the XMLs, not just one specific XML file. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What about XSLT?

Comment: I am rather new to R and XML, and I have never used XSLT so I have no idea how I could use it to remove the <ref> tags.  Any suggestions you have would be appreciated.

Comment: Your XML is not well-formed. The `<div>` element has no closing tag.

Comment: Whoops, there is one in the actual XML, I just copied over a portion of it and forgot to include the closing tag here but if you click the link in my code above, you will see the </div>

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0.

Answer (score -1):

Here is XSLT to remove all *ref* elements.

**Input XML**

```
<text xml:lang="en">
    <body>
        <div xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
            <head n="1.">Introduction</head>
            <p>Thermal properties of confectionary products, including the melting temperature (Tm) of crystalline components and glass transition temperature (Tg) of amorphous components, as well as the crystalline to amorphous ratio, significantly impact system texture and stability
                <ref type="bibr" target="#b23">(Levine and Slade, 1986)</ref>. Predominantly amorphous (non-crystalline, disordered solid) candies are formed by heating ingredients to a set temperature and then quickly cooling the resultant supersatured sugar solution to below the temperature range in which recrystallization of sugars can occur, between Tg and Tm of the material.</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</text>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns1="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
   <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

    <!-- remove ref elements -->
   <xsl:template match="ns1:ref"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output XML**

```
<text xml:lang="en">
  <body>
    <div xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
      <head n="1.">Introduction</head>
      <p>Thermal properties of confectionary products, including the melting temperature (Tm) of crystalline components and glass transition temperature (Tg) of amorphous components, as well as the crystalline to amorphous ratio, significantly impact system texture and stability
                . Predominantly amorphous (non-crystalline, disordered solid) candies are formed by heating ingredients to a set temperature and then quickly cooling the resultant supersatured sugar solution to below the temperature range in which recrystallization of sugars can occur, between Tg and Tm of the material.
      </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</text>
```

Comment: Hmm, trying to apply that and I get the following 2 errors: "xslt error: runtime error" file C:/.....xsl line 7 element copy" and "xslt error: Attribute nodes must be added before any child nodes to an element"

Comment: I added a comment below your original question. Please provide ##1-4

Comment: I updated the answer by using sample XML fragment as input XML. I added a namespace handling to the XSLT. and even added Output XML - a result of the XSLT Transformation.